# Launching flask on a server: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I'm trying run flask on apache server and following the instructions on

[this page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/mod_wsgi/) but getting No module named 'flask' error

here's error.log

```
[Tue Aug 14 20:53:59.945197 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16744] [remote 189.46.121.20:52032] mod_wsgi (pid=16744): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/flask-admin/examples/forms/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Aug 14 20:53:59.945263 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16744] [remote 189.46.121.20:52032] mod_wsgi (pid=16744): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/flask-admin/examples/forms/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Tue Aug 14 20:53:59.945394 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16744] [remote 189.46.121.20:52032] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Aug 14 20:53:59.945425 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16744] [remote 189.46.121.20:52032]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/flask-admin/examples/forms/flaskapp.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
[Tue Aug 14 20:53:59.945431 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16744] [remote 189.46.121.20:52032]     from app123 import app as application
[Tue Aug 14 20:53:59.945438 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16744] [remote 189.46.121.20:52032]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/flask-admin/examples/forms/app123.py", line 4, in <module>
[Tue Aug 14 20:53:59.945442 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16744] [remote 189.46.121.20:52032]     from flask import Flask, url_for, flash
[Tue Aug 14 20:53:59.945466 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16744] [remote 189.46.121.20:52032] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

FlaskApp.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 1**.1**.**.**
    WSGIDaemonProcess app123
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/flask-admin/examples/forms/flaskapp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/flask-admin/examples/forms>
        WSGIProcessGroup app123
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi - file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/flask-admin/examples/forms/")

#from FlaskApp 
from app123 import app as application
application.secret_key = 'j****'

activate_this = 'py3env/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

and the app123.py file is the simple flask-admin example with forms. Absolutely the same. So, the question is: where is the problem?

Comment: Is flask pip installed on the server? If so, is the python executable pointing to the right `site-packages`? It could be a default python installation that doesn't share the same config as say a `virtualenv` or `conda env`

Comment: @C.Nivs no, everything installed properly, especially - flask. Inside virtualenv

Comment: @C.Nivs I think the problem is only with installing flask, but I installed it. How to check that python executable pointing to the right site-packages?

Comment: `activate_this = 'py3env/bin/activate_this.py'` Per the docs, this has to be an absolute path. Could be that it's not activating the environment properly

Comment: @C.Nivs This solved my problem! Thank's a lot!!